Simple cascode biasing problem in an electronic circuit
use variable (_, _,_) to express the range
Assume that all 4*(W/L)1= (W/L)2= (W/L)3= (W/L)4= (W/L)5= (W/L)6
All TRs are under saturation region
Assume that M2 is under subthreshold region (VGS2 ≤ Vth and VDS2  ≥ Vdsat2)
We need to find the minimum output voltage that satisfies the given conditions. I am not sure what changes when M1 becomes 1/4. Even running SPICE simulations makes it difficult to determine the values. Is there anyone who can explain each process?
I understand that VDS should be VGS - VTH, but in the case of M2 or M4, VD becomes equal to VGS, so I am stuck on how to calculate it.

